# Comparison of image with csv column in loop python

Tags: python-3.x, image, loops, comparison

Gretings,

**Problem:**
I am stuck in a loop. I want the loop to pick image and compare it with csv column(name) if it exists then move further to resizing. Images were in a zip, first I took them out of zip;

```js
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = "human_detection_images.zip"
with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
   zip.extractall()
print('Done')

PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = pathlib.Path('/content/human_detection_images')
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = sorted(list(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR.glob("*.jpg")))
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS
```

Then I upload csv, which has labels and names of images (same as folder but not in sequence).

```js
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data1 = pd.read_csv('/content/csvnew.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df.shape,df.columns
```

Now I need to run a loop which pick 1 by 1 images and compare it with names in csv. If similar it resize the image. resize code is available,

```js
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
   if TEST_IMAGE_PATHS == df['names']:
     print("done") #error here: it prints nothing
  #  return False
     imgs = read_given_images("./",TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
     points = df['labels']
     points = np.array(points)

# resizing starts
```

I need help with the loop. if anyone please..

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. First pick name from csv and find it in folder.
your code:

```
     imgs = read_given_images("./",TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
 points = df['labels']
 points = np.array(points)
```

change it to:

```js
imgs = read_given_images("/content/human_detection_images",df.names.values)
points = df['labels'].values
points = np.array(points)
```

this way images and points will be picked together.